# Barebones sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have been asked to make a simple sort aglorithm to sort a random series of 6 numbers into numerical order. However, I have been asked to do this using Barebones-a theoretical language put forward in the book `Computer Science, an Overview`.

Some information on the language can be found [here](http://www.brouhaha.com/~eric/software/barebones/).

Just to clarify, I am a student teacher and have been doing anaysis on "mini-programing languages" and their uses in a teaching environment. I suggested to my tutor that I look at barebones (the language) and asked what sort of exmaple program I should write. He suggested a simple sort algorithm. Now since looking at the language I can't understand how I can do this without using arrays and `if` statements.

The code to swap the value of variables would be

```
while a not 0 do;
    incr Aux1;
    decr a;
end;
while b not 0 do;
    incr Aux2
    decr b
end;
while Aux1 not 0 do;
    incr a;
    decr Aux1;
end;
while Aux2 not 0 do;
    incr b;
    decr Aux2;
end;
```

However, the language does not provide < or > operators.

What could I use as a workaround?

Comment: I see the language has no array. Not even an if statement! I guess that whoever asked you to do this wanted you to work hard to understand the essence of computation. 
I would suggest you edit your question adding your attempts to the exercise

Comment: My workflow: 1. retag; 2. read what meta says about it. Meh.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, come on, start thinking about the problem!

What's an array?  A list of variables.

So Barebones doesn't have an if statement?  It's got while loops.

Get on with your homework.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting exercise.

I would suggest you try to first implement the following:

- Swap values of two variables
- Set a variable (say z) to zero if value of variable x >= value of variable y.

Since the program is supposed to sort exactly 6 integers, I suppose you can assume they are in the variables x1, x2, .., x6.

In the end we need: x1 <= x2 <= ... <= x6.

Comment: to swap the values of 2 variables the code would be along the lines of

while a not 0 do;
 incr Aux1;
 decr a;
end;
while b not 0 do;
 incr Aux2
 decr b
end;
while Aux1 not 0 do;
 incr a;
 decr Aux1;
end;
while Aux2 not 0 do;
 incr b;
 decr Aux2;
end;

however the language provides no implementation of > or < operators and therefore am stuggling to work out how to solve this problem(unless i am missing something stupid)

Comment: sorry should'nt have put that above